# Anycubic Kossel Delta switch from Trigorilla to MKS Gen L 1.0

Tags: marlin, delta, kossel, mks

I have an Anycubic Kossel Delta 3D Printer.
The original Trigorilla motherboard died and I decided to buy one but I only found a Makerboard MKS Gen L 1.0 which is said to be compatible with Trigorilla.

My questions are:
I have 2 fan ports on Trigorilla and 1 in MKS. I have 2 power supply connectors in Trigorilla (5A, 11A) and I have 1 (12/24V) in MKS Gen L. My power supply (which originally comes with Kossel) has 2 power connectors. (2 + red and 2 - black) How can I use the new MKS Gen L board with Kossel?

My official Trigorilla wiring:
[image]

MKS Gen L 1.0 wiring:
[image]